# How do I pass a list of files to grep

Tags: grep, find, pipe

I am using `find` and getting a list of files I want to `grep` through. How do I pipe that list to `grep`?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Well, the generic case that works with any command that writes to stdout is to use `xargs`, which will let you attach any number of command-line arguments to the end of a command:

```
$ find … | xargs grep 'search'
```

Or to embed the command in your `grep` line with backticks or `$()`, which will run the command and substitute its output:

```
$ grep 'search' $(find …)
```

Note that these commands don't work if the file names contain whitespace, or certain other “weird characters” (`\'"` for xargs, `\[*?` for `$(find …)`).

---

However, in the specific case of `find` the ability to execute a program on the given arguments is built-in:

```
$ find … -exec grep 'search' {} \;
```

Everything between `-exec` and `;` is the command to execute; `{}` is replaced with the filename found by `find`. That will execute a separate `grep` for each file; since `grep` can take many filenames and search them all, you can change the `;` to `+` to tell find to pass all the matching filenames to `grep` at once:

```
$ find … -exec grep 'search' {} \+
```

Comment: Should be noted that first two forms do not works with filenames containing spaces.

Comment: I prefer `find ... -type f -print0 | xargs -r0 grep 'search' /dev/null`. QED.  While `-exec +` is very efficient, it does not exist on all version of find.

Comment: Sadly I can not check you correct 3 times.

Comment: I suggest using the `-exec`, rather than than the `xargs`. If you use the `-exec` in [`find`](http://www.folkstalk.com/2011/12/101-examples-of-using-find-command-in.html), it will create only one shell to [grep](http://www.folkstalk.com/2011/12/101-examples-of-using-find-command-in.html) for the content. If you use the `xargs`, it will create two shells: one for the `find` and the other for the `xargs`.

Comment: by experiment I find that the `$ find … -exec grep 'search' {} \+` form is *much* the fastest.

Answer (score 11):

Some versions of `grep` (e.g. on non-embedded Linux or [BSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=grep) or Mac OS X) have a `-r` option to make a recursive search. On OpenBSD, use `-R` (and there's no `--exclude` as in the example below). This covers simple combinations of `find` with `grep`.

If your implementation doesn't have the `-R` flag, or if you want fancier file matching criteria, you can use the `-exec` primary of `find` to make it execute `grep`. A few older `find` implementations don't support `-exec` … `+`; on these systems, use a `;` instead of the `+` (this will call `grep` once per file, so it'll be slower, but otherwise the result will be the same). Note the `/dev/null` trick to cause `grep` to show the file name even if it happens to be called on a single file (GNU grep and FreeBSD/NetBSD/OSX grep have a `-H` option to achieve the same effect).

```
find . -type f -name '*.o' -prune -o -exec grep 'needle' /dev/null {} +
grep -r --exclude='*.o' 'needle' .
```

Comment: `GNU grep` has `-H` option to always print filename.

Answer (score 3):

```
find ... | while read line; do grep <regex> "$line"; done
```

Comment: Although your approach is quite straightforward, please find the time to add a minimum of explanation. Also, please note that this shares the same problem that most of the other answers have in that it relies on [parsing the output of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice?noredirect=1&lq=1) which should be avoided due to possible problems with special characters in filenames (although that may be repairable depending on the shell used).

Answer (score 1):

example :

search for a file which have "Delay" in its name and which have "Create" somewhere inside the found file

```
find . | grep Delay | xargs grep 'Create'
```

it should then, if it finds something, display each line where the word 'Create' is written.