# How to grep all path from file

Tags: shell-script

I have the number of log file in each individual paths of list.txt file. I have to access each induvial path and grep error from that .log file. What will be the code in shell scripting.

E.g The contents of list.txt file is

```
 /slows/us01dwt11/tsn/aessj1.log 
 /slows/us01dwt11/tsn/faessj2.log
 /slows/us01dwt11/tsn/laessj3.log
 /slows/us01dwt11/tsn/aaessj1.log
```

Comment: You should show an example of the contents of your "particular file", as the required commands will depend on the exact format of the file. Please edit the information into your original question; don't add information in comments.

Comment: Show us the input, and the desired output. As it stands I have no idea what you are asking. Try to avoid technical words unless you know 100% what they mean, and proof read, and improve your grammar.

Comment: You need to read lines : https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-howto-read-line-by-line-from-file/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a list of files to grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20262/how-do-i-pass-a-list-of-files-to-grep)